# How to change only date in @timestamp using logstash date filter?

Tags: date, time, filter, timestamp, logstash

I am using date filter. I just want to update date and want to keep time as it is.

I am using following date filter:

```
date{
    timezone => "UTC"
    match => [ "My_TIMESTAMP", "dd.MM.yy" ]
}
```

But when I match only date, date is matched and time resets to zero. Is there any way to update only date while keeping time as it is?

Help me out

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd thing to do, but...

Grab the time from @timestamp and the date from your log, merge them together with add_field, and then feed that to date{}.

Certainly you can get the time portion with the ruby{} filter, and it might also be possible to copy @timestamp to another field with mutate->add_field and mutate->gsub{} off the date.